# eclipse IDE autocomplete extensions

Tags: java, eclipse

My system is MacOS Ventura 13.2.1 (22D68) and eclipse version is : 2023-09 (4.29.0).

sysout tab doesn't autocomplete to `System.out.print()` or `System.out.print()`. Also the suggestion code doesn't autocomplete many a times. Is there any extension in Eclipse Marketplace to smoothen these things?

Comment: By default, the shortcut for autocomplete is Ctrl+Space, not Tab.